# Using a .xib File in a Self-Contained Custom UIView Subclass for Prototyping Purposes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

In my experience, the most robust view/viewcontroller implementations do all of their element creation and layout directly in the UIView subclass (in `initWithFrame:` and `layoutSubviews`), rather than using a .xib file. While one can certainly use a .xib file to achieve the same result, the complexity and maintenance doesn't seem worth the trouble. I recently started working on a custom view controller and UIView subclass, for which I am using the PFLogInViewController from the ParseUI framework as a reference to create this '.xib-free' robustness that I need.

My custom UIView subclass (which I will call `NumPadView` as an example) is responsible for laying out buttons, labels, and other UI elements, while my custom UIViewController subclass (which I will call `NumPadViewController` as an example) is responsible for creating the `NumPadView` instance and adding target actions to all of its buttons, and then implementing those actions. Here is an example interface for `NumPadView`:

```
//
//  NumPadView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NumPadView : UIScrollView
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button1;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button2;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button3;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button4;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button5;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button6;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button7;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button8;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button9;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button0;
- (instancetype)init;
@end
```

Using this interface, `NumPadViewController` (with a `_numPadView` property) can do things such as:

```
self.view = _numPadView;
[_numPadView.button0 addTarget:self selector:@selector(button0Pressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now, to get to my question. Eventually, all of the `NumPadView` layout will be done in code, similar to the following:

```
//
//  NumPadView.m

#import "NumPadView.h"

@interface NumPadView ()
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button1;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button2;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button3;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button4;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button5;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button6;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button7;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button8;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button9;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UIButton *button0;
@end

@implementation NumPadView
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        //...
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    self.button1.frame = //...
    //...
}
@end
```

However, I always do the layout/UI design as the last step because I want to make sure that everything functions first. I will therefore spend my time implementing methods in `NumPadViewController`, rather than coding the layout in `NumPadView`. Of course, to test the functionality of the view controller, I will need some sort of UI to interact with. I would like to make a quick prototype UI using a .xib file and attaching it to the `NumPadView`. I don't want to change the interface of the `NumPadView` at all, as that would require changes to my `NumPadViewController`. So my problem is figuring out how to create and load a .xib from *within* the `NumPadView` implementation. Of course, .xibs are typically owned by a view controller and IBOutlets are linked to properties in said view controller, but I want to shift all of that to the private implementation of `NumPadView` like such:

```
//
//  NumPadView.m

#import "NumPadView.h"

@interface NumPadView ()
//Link private interface properties to .xib file
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button4;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button5;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button6;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button7;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button8;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button9;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIButton *button0;
@end

@implementation NumPadView
- (instancetype)init
{
    //I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but I'm looking for something similar in effect.
    self = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self class]] owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    return self;
}
@end
```

So, how can I effectively implement this? I've tried using `loadFromNib:`, but the button properties always end up being `nil`. I've connected all of the IBOutlets in the interface builder and set the file owner on `NumPadView.xib` to `NumPadView` and the class of the main view to `UIScrollView` (I've tried `NumPadView` as well). In addition to advice on how to successfully implement this scheme, I am certainly open better ways of doing this whole prototyping scheme if anyone has a better method. The most important thing is that the `NumPadView` maintain a consistent interface and that the `NumPadViewController` has no knowledge of the .xib file. This concept seems to be missed in similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246074/uiview-subclass-with-its-own-xib) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314818/custom-uiview-loaded-from-xib). Thank you for your input; I look forward to reading your answers.

Comment: P.S. Please learn about arrays and outlet collections. No need for 10 separate outlet properties.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't quite do what you're doing, because that's not how nib loading works. A nib has a File's Owner. The outlets to the external world, as it were, are to that owner. Thus if a NumPadView is the top-level object in the nib, then a NumPadView cannot be the owner, because what you end up with is *another* NumPadView (the one in the nib). And if *another* object is the owner - which is the usual thing - then outlets should not be from the buttons to the File's Owner, which would be pointless, but to the NumPadView in the nib. (There will also usually need to be an outlet from the NumPadView in the nib to the File's Owner so that the owner can retrieve the NumPadView from the nib and do something with it.)

So you need to think about where your outlets are hooked up in the nib, *what* the File's Owner is (what class), and *who* the actual owner is at load time. If you structure things accordingly, so that they match up in the internal world of the nib and the external world of the loader, all will be well.

Comment: Further discussion, and an example of loading and retrieving an arbitrary object from a nib, here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_nib_loading_and_file_8217_s_owner

Comment: And of course this sort of thing is what we _always_ do for something like a table view cell in a nib: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_designing_a_cell_in_a_nib

Comment: Do you know of any better ways to prototype UIs like I am trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: What you're doing is great. You just have to structure your nib and loading correctly and consistently with each other, as I said in my answer.